# Bootstrap submenu does not collapse

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Fellow friends,

I have following bootstrap based menu that does not collapse for some reason. The menu is generated by WordPress and I am using bootstrap. What could be causing this and what would be the resolution?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-29 dropdown"><a title="Therapieën" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">Therapieën <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-86"><a title="Logopedie" href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/logopedie/">Logopedie</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85"><a title="Bijlessen" href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/bijlessen/">Bijlessen</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-84"><a title="Audiologie" href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/audiologie/">Audiologie</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83"><a title="Stemtherapie" href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/stemtherapie/">Stemtherapie</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a title="Verder ook begeleiding in" href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/verder-ook-begeleiding-in/">Verder ook begeleiding in</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you create a bootply so we can see the code working?

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Is you bootstrap working?

Comment: Do you have jquery included?

Comment: make jsfiddle/plunker

Comment: No console errors. Jquery v1.12.4 is used.

Comment: Found the issue: seems i had added jquery twice in my code as well as the bootstrap css suite. I remove the duplicate entries and now it works.

Comment: make jsfiddle/plunker, no one can simply guess

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because the code is incomplete. Try this :

```
<div class="dropdown">
<li>
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Therapieën <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ><a href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/logopedie/">Logopedie</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/bijlessen/">Bijlessen</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/audiologie/">Audiologie</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>

</div>
```

Notice the class `dropdown` of the `<div>`, `data-toggle`of `<a>` ann `<dropdown-menu>`. They must follow that specific order in tags of same level. you can't put `class="dropdown"` in a `<li>` for instance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-29 dropdown"><a title="Therapieën" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true">Therapieën <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu">
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-86" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-86"><a title="Logopedie" href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/logopedie/">Logopedie</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-85" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-85"><a title="Bijlessen" href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/bijlessen/">Bijlessen</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-84" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-84"><a title="Audiologie" href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/audiologie/">Audiologie</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-83" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-83"><a title="Stemtherapie" href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/stemtherapie/">Stemtherapie</a></li>
    <li itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82"><a title="Verder ook begeleiding in" href="http://localhost:81/wordpress/verder-ook-begeleiding-in/">Verder ook begeleiding in</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>


</body>
</html>
```